# Continuous Form as Subform - Can't Modify Data

Tags: forms, ms-access, subforms

I have added a continuous form as a subform to a single form.  When I view the form in Form View I am unable to modify the data contained in the subform (which is continuous).  When I open the continuous form as a standalone form I am able to modify the data.

Ultimately, I want to add multiple continuous forms as subforms to the main form.  Has anyone ever seen this issue?

Comment: Can you edit data in the parent form? It sounds like the master form has something that prevents edits. If that form cannot edit data in the main table, then likely it cannot edit data in the sub form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same problem in the past. The solution is in the data tab of the form property. Take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

It's a german localisation but I am sure you handle it. Change these settings around (yes or no) and test if it works. I do not remember which property exactly solves your problem but it is one of those four.

Reason behind it: With these properties you can alter the behaviour of the form. Sometimes you want a form that just shows data without letting the user make changes to the data.